# API Triggered Emails not sending

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

i´m using the REST API to send triggered Emails, everything was working perfectly a few days ago, but now when i send a request for a triggered Email i get a "202 Accepted" code, and the API says the Email has been put in the Quee, but i don´t seee anything in the Exactarget Account. Even when i send incorrect fields in the SubscriberAttributes i still get a success code.
What can be happening?

Comment: Can you post some of the code, like the exact route you are using. That will help to solve the issue a bit better.

Answer (score 0):

If your trigger is writing to a Data Extension, do an [email validation](https://help.exacttarget.com/en-US/documentation/exacttarget/content/validate/) on the email you're triggering.  That'll generally tell you if it's a problem with the data you're passing in your API call.  This is helpful since the data is written to the DE before the email is fired off.

If that doesn't give you any clues, SFMC support can tell you why it didn't send.  They have access to the server error log.